# cURL: manage download errors

Tags: bash, curl, http-headers

I tried to wrote a Bash script to manage cURL download errors by parsing the response header. However, with all Github downloads, after the redirect the header is `HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden`, despite the fact that the download works.

```
function curldown {

    url="$1"
    code=$(curl -LI $url | awk '/^HTTP/{a=$2} END{print a}')

    if [[ "${code:0:1}"  == "4" ]]; then
    echo "Error $code"
    else
    curl -JOL $url > /tmp/curldown
    fi

}

url='https://github.com/keybase/client/releases/download/v5.1.1/keybase-v5.1.1.tar.xz'
curldown $url
# Error 403
```

but

```
curl -JOL $url
```

gives a working output.

Any fix?

Answer (score 1):

A better solution :

```
http_code=$(curl -Ls "$url" -w '%{http_code}\n' -o /dev/null)

if ((http_code >= 400)); then
    echo >&2 "Error detected; HTTP code $http_code"
fi
```

Comment: I have a strange behaviour. With the provided Github URL, which redirects to Amazon, if using `curl -LI`, I get a 302 and 403 response code, but `curl -JOL $url` works. Your code gives a 200 code, but takes very long to process the page. By removing `-o /dev/null`,  its response is immediate, but if the data is non binary, I get the page content printed.